# Need to know all possible 4 numbers that can be +,-,multiply,divided to result a specific number

Tags: c#, math, numbers

I want to create a function to which i will pass a number as a parameter (`like 8`) and it will return the list of all possible combinations consisting of `4 different numbers` and `3 different operators` , which are addition (+), subtraction (-) , division (/) or multiplication(*)

e.g:

```
4 * 2 + 4 - 1 = 11
```

I will pass `11` to the function as a parameter and it will return all possible combinations like the one in above. One restriction is that every numbers from the four `will not be greater then 15`.

It's better to use C#.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: There are an infinite number of combinations, consider for example 11*1*1*1*1... Perhaps you will want to enforce more restrictions to keep the combinations infinite.

Comment: we can only use four number, not more then or less then four numbers.
e.g:
4*2+4-1 = 11
10+5-5+1 = 11

Comment: I see, interesting :-)

Comment: Are you allowed to add 0 or multiply by 1 etc, essentially using fewer than four numbers?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend doing a brute force as the number of combinations are so few. Just go through the four arithmetic operations for the first number for all numbers 0-15, then repeat for the next etc. Yeild all combinations that results in e.g. 11. This is no match for a modern computer. No need for any fancy algorithms. There are more clever ways to do this, but are somewhat trickier to implement.

Comment: You do need to be a little careful with parsing and follow PEMDAS which makes even a brute force algorithm kinda tricky.

Answer (score 0):

There's an infinite number of answers here. Say you pass in 11:

15 - 4 + 5 - 5 = 11

15 - 3 + 5 - 6 = 11

15 - 2 ...

You're going to have to bound this harder if you want an actual answer

To put it in terms of an equation, you're asking for all the discrete solutions to

a + b + c + d = 11, where a,b,c,d<=15. If you bound it on the lower end, say so that 0 <= a,b,c,d <= 15, you'd still have a very large number of answers but at least it'd be bounded.

Edit:

Ok. You said constraints of 0 <= a,b,c,d <= 15. This isn't going to be pretty.

```
int[] possibleNums = new int[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
```

with possible operators + - * /

```
char[] operators = new char[] {'+', '-', '*', '/'};
```

Now you want all operations using any combination of those that equals the input number.

```
int WhyWouldIEverDoThis(int num) {
    int counter = 0;
    foreach(var a in possibleNums) {
        foreach(var op1 in operators) {
            foreach(var b in possibleNums) {
                foreach(var op2 in operators) {
                    foreach(var c in possibleNums) {
                        foreach(var op3 in operators) {
                            foreach(var d in possibleNums) {
                                int result = 0;
                                if(op1 == '*' || op1 == '/') {
                                    result = applyOperator(a,b,op1);
                                    if(op2 == '*' || op2 == '/') {
                                        result = applyOperator(applyOperator(result, c, op1), d, op3);
                                    } else if (op3 == '*' || op3 == '/') {
                                        result = applyOperator(result, applyOperator(c,d,op3), op2);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    if(op2 == '*' || op2 == '/') {
                                        if(op3 == '*' || op3 == '/') {
                                            result = applyOperator(a, applyOperator(applyOperator(b,c,op2), d, op3), op1);
                                        } else {
                                            result = applyOperator(a, applyOperator(b,c,op2), op1);
                                            result = applyOperator(result, d, op3);
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        result += applyOperator(a,b,op1);
                                        if(op3 == '*' || op3 == '/') {
                                            result = applyOperator(result, applyOperator(c,d,op3), op2);
                                        } else {
                                            result = applyOperator(result, c, op2);
                                            result = applyOperator(result, d, op3);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                if(result == num)
                                    counter++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int applyOperator(int a, int b, char operator) {
    if(operator == '+') {
        return a + b;
    } else if (operator == '-') {
        return a - b;
    } else if (operator == '*') {
        return a * b;
    } else {
        return a / b;
    }
}
```

I think this would work. It's horrendous, and likely has a bug or two in it, but it's the general idea and I don't really see a better way to do it.

Are you looking to return all combinations? Or just a count of how many combinations?

Comment: One more restriction can be that the input number will be less then 20. And obviously there will be large number of answers but there will a code which can calculate and return the answer. So i need that code which will do the work.\